# JavaDoc method signature indentation

Tags: java, newline, javadoc, indentation, code-formatting

I tend to use a lot of line breaks in my code to keep things mostly within the 80-character line width. While some might find this utterly useless, I like to edit code on a vertically rotated screen and also like this narrow layout when doing diffs. Regardless of preference, this did give me an unexpected result when generating JavaDoc, more specifically the method signatures.

Suppose I have the following:

```
public static 
        <C extends AcmeConstants, 
        B extends AcmeBundle<C>, 
        R extends AcmeBundleProvider<C, B>> //Type params
        R //Return type
        newInstance(final Class<R> spiClass, final String implementationClassName) 
        throws AcmeException {

    return newInstance(spiClass, 
                       implementationClassName, 
                       Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
}
```

Crazy type parameters aside, as you can see I'm aligning the type params, return type, method declaration and throws clause to keep things somewhat distinct. Again, you may find this charming or downright retarded, but the problem occurs when generating JavaDoc. What I get is documentation where the method arguments are each on a new line and aligned, even though I didn't do that. Not really a problem, although oddly it turns the type parameter declaration into one line. The real kicker, however, is that it then puts the throws clause on a new line as well, with original indentation!

Have a look to see what I mean:

```
public static <C extends AcmeConstants,B extends AcmeBundle<C>,R extends AcmeBundleProvider<C,B>> R newInstance(Class<R> spiClass,
                                                                                                                 String implementationClassName)
                                                               throws AcmeException
```

That's pretty much exactly as it looks in the generated JavaDoc. Is there any way to make it stop doing this and normalize white space or something? Right now I have to choose between changing my code formatting or having weird JavaDoc.

By the way, I'm generating with the Maven JavaDoc plugin, but the result was the same when using different methods.

Comment: I believe you can edit the css that javadoc created pages will use.  That might get you some of what you want.  But honestly?  I'd leave it alone.  While it might bug you, it's kind of the defacto standard.  Set your OCD aside and focus on getting real work done.  (Something I always struggle with myself, so I know where you're coming from.)

Comment: @Marvo Haha, it's OCD alright :D Probably spend way too much time formatting code. At least I've stopped breaking up String literals in exception throws over multiple lines. Regarding the CSS, I'm afraid it won't help here. The generated HTML uses a `PRE` tag that's causing all white space to appear exactly as it's in the file.

Comment: Yeah, the handling of long type parameter declaration in Javadoc is not really optimal. There is no relation to your source code formatting, though (as jackrabbit said).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Javadoc is generated by a [Doclet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/index.html), which only gets to see a parsed version of your code. That it aligns the throws clause similarly to your original source is coincidence. The signature you see is actually generated from a [MethodDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/com/sun/javadoc/MethodDoc.html) handed by the framework to the Doclet. Short of changing the Doclet code, you can not change the output format. Nothing prevents you from post-processing it, but I doubt it will be worth the effort.

BTW, alternative doclets are [available](http://doclet.com/) on the internet, which may be more suitable to customization.

Comment: Indeed, just tried and it the code has no bearing on the output formatting. That seemed to make sense from the start, but it was such a coincidence that I failed to see it. It's really odd that the resulting formatting looks so strange, never really noticed that before when viewing JavaDocs.

Thanks for the clarification! Since there's nothing to be done about it short of customizing, I'll just leave it as it is.